# Programatically Managing an Outlook Distribution List

Tags: c#, list, scripting, outlook, automation

I am trying to automate the management of an Outlook distribution list. Currently, if I want to add/remove users from a DL, I have to go into the Outlook GUI and manually modify the membership of the DL. The task becomes tedious and rather error prone.

Can anyone shed light on what tools,technologies and steps I can use to accomplish this?

I am a beginner who is doing this particular effort at work, as a personal development project for growing more technical skills.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a VBA code or develop an Outlook add-in. It depends whether you are going to deploy your solution on other PCs. VBA macros are not designed for distributing on multiple PCs.

I'd suggest starting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx) article. Then you can find a lot of articles with a sample code in the [Concepts (Outlook 2013 developer reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868025(v=office.15).aspx) section.

Finally, you may find the [How To: Create a new distribution list item in Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/03/29/create-outlook-distribution-list/) article helpful. It looks like you are interested in the [AddMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff864726(v=office.14).aspx) and [RemoveMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff863711(v=office.14).aspx) methods of the [DistListItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff860361(v=office.14).aspx) class.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I will research VBA. From what I am reading so far via your links, that does seem to be the best route to start.